My service is not able to connect to my MySQL DB instance
I am not able to connect my service to my MYSQL-DB. My docker compose is
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://db:3306/image2work
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: user1
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: 12345678
    networks:
      - i2wnetwork
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    expose:
      - "3306"
    environment:
      - 'MYSQL_DATABASE=image2work'
      - 'MYSQL_PASSWORD=12345678'
      - 'MYSQL_USER=user1'
      - 'MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root123'
    networks:
      - i2wnetwork

networks:
  i2wnetwork:
    driver: bridge


The error it is throwing is
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

My database is running fine but I am not able to connect it to my instance. My database URL as shown in docker desktop is
http://localhost:3306/

Communication link Failure occurs when your server is not able to connect with database itself, there can be multiple reasons for that but most happening reason is,

The database instance does not have traffic allowed from that docker
you will need to add subnet or security group of doctor servers to db allowed traffic list.


The error message you're encountering, Communications link failure, typically indicates that the application is unable to establish a connection to the MySQL database. This can occur due to various reasons such as network configuration issues, incorrect database credentials, or the MySQL server not being ready to accept connections.
Here are a few steps you can take to troubleshoot the issue:


Check Database Container Status: Ensure that the db container is running and healthy. You can check this by running docker ps in your terminal.


Verify Database Credentials: Double-c


